# getstream.io how to create filter for profile only

Tags: java, integration, feed, getstream-io

I am creating a newsfeed, using [stream](http://getstream.io/), they allow you to apply filters, so you can get the results that you want, see below:

```
Feed feed = getStreamClient().newFeed("user", user);
FeedFilter filter = new FeedFilter.Builder().withLimit(size).withOffset(pageNumber).build();
List<SimpleActivity> activities = feed.newFlatActivityService(SimpleActivity.class).getActivities(filter).getResults();
```

This however return all the activities, which include my activities and also the users i follow, how would i filter so it only returns my activities, which where created by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified that you should store user activities in user feeds and have a different kind of feed to show activities from followed users. Eg. user X likes something, you add an activity to user X’s user feed. user Y follows user X, you let user Y’s newsfeed follow user X’s user feed. When you start an app on Stream, you get 4 different kinds of feeds by default: user, flat, aggregated and notification.